# Bridging two interfaces together, forward traffic

Tags: networking, 18.04, netplan, network-bridge

I'm currently trying to create a setup that forwards traffic through a Ubuntu server to a switch, which then multiple servers will be connected to (each assigned an individual IP(s)) The Ubuntu server has a PCI NIC and a on-board port.

The PCI NIC (enp0s25) is connected to the outside world, then it should pipe out of the on-board port (enp1s0) to the switch.

I was reading into network bridges but I can't seem to figure out how to bridge two interfaces together like that. The reason for this server is to act as a firewall above the switch (running stuff with XDP/eBPF for advanced filtering).

My current netplan config looks as the following:

```
network:
    version: 2
ethernets:
    enp1s0:
        dhcp4: true
    enp0s25:
        dhcp4: true
bridges:
    br0:
        interfaces: [enp1s0]
        dhcp4: true
        optional: true
```

This obviously isn't working. I'm quite new to networking so interested in learning all of this.